# Best way handle project with 50000 files uploaded (with prevision uploaded to infinite)

Tags: file-management

How can I handle a massive upload and downloaded files(png, jpg, xls, pdf, ...)? I need control backup and search. What is the best way to do it?
I think in different ways:

1. Save in database.
2. Use DMS.
3. Do a java code create my folders (I hate this way but is now  working in project and we doesn´t controll backup)

If somebody knows other way I'll be very grateful.

Comment: by search you mean just filenames and/or other metadata outside content or file-content too like the text in a xml file?

Comment: filenames and get file to send client

Comment: 'best' is a dangerous word ;) Be great if you could clarify exactly what features you want

Comment: I really want is a way to save, remove, update or send files. I want can do it security copies of this files. I want handle this files avoiding hardcode and lost me in thousand folders. Actually folders are per data(sales, buys,...), department(spain, uk,...) and year

Comment: Do you need only backup and search? Only 1 user, or several users? I don't understand "Do a java code create my folders", could you explain in more details? Thanks!

Comment: Is it OK if users access via a web interface?

Comment: I have web interface with many operations, one are upload and download files like bills, reports, pictures, ... My doubt are how can control this efficient way.